# Particular solution of $y''-4y'+5y = 4e^{2x} (\sin x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How do I find the particular solution of this second order inhomogenous differential equation? (Using undetermined coefficients).

$y''-4y'+5y = 4e^{2x} (\sin x)$

I can find the generel homogenous solutions but I need help for the particular.

Comment: Easiest way would be to guess the form of the solution, and use undetermined coefficients. Try $y = Ae^{2x}\sin{x} + Be^{2x}\cos{x}$. Plug that into the DE and find out what $A, B$ are.

Comment: What does your textbook say about this?

Comment: What method do you typically use to get particular soutions?  Undetermined coefficients?  Variation of parameters?  Laplace transforms?  How we help you depends on the approach you are taking.

Answer (score 2):

Since the auxiliary equation

$$ (m-2)^2+1=0 \tag{1}$$

has solutions $m=2\pm i$ we know that the solution to the complementary equation is

$$y_c=e^{2x}(c_1\cos x+c_2\sin x) $$

which has the same form as the forcing function. So $y_p$ cannot take that form. In order to annihilate the forcing function we would need an annihilator of the form $(D-2)^2+1$  giving the annihilated equation an auxiliary function

$$ [(m-2)^2+1]^2=0 $$

So each of the roots of equation $(1)$ becomes a double root of the annihilated equation.

Subtracting out the common forms between the solution of the annihilated equation and the solution of the complementary equation leaves us with the correct form of the particular solution

$$y_p=xe^{2x}(A\cos x+B\sin x)$$

Answer (score 1):

**By Inverse Operator Rule:** When $f(D)y=X$ where X is a function of $x$ or constant then,

Particular Integral, $P.I.=\dfrac{1}{f(D)}X$.

**Rule 1.** When $X=\sin(ax+b)$, or, $\cos(ax+b)$ then
\begin{align*}
P.I.&=\dfrac{1}{f(D^2)}\sin(ax+b)\  \text{ put }D^2=-a^2,\text{ when }[f(-a^2)\neq0]\\
&=x\dfrac{1}{f'(D^2)}\sin(ax+b)\  \text{ put }D^2=-a^2,\text{ when }[f(-a^2)=0,\ f'(-a^2)\neq0]\\
&=x^2\dfrac{1}{f''(D^2)}\sin(ax+b)\  \text{ put }D^2=-a^2,\text{ when }[f'(-a^2)=0,\ f''(-a^2)\neq0]\\
&=\cdots
\end{align*}

**Rule 2.** When $X=e^{ax}V$, then $P.I.=\dfrac{1}{f(D)}e^{ax}V=e^{ax}\dfrac{1}{f(D+a)}V$.

So in your problem,
\begin{align*}
P.I.&=\dfrac{1}{D^2-4D+5}\left(4e^{2x}\sin x\right)\\
&=4\cdot\dfrac{1}{D^2-4D+5}\left(e^{2x}\sin x\right)\\
&=4e^{2x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{(D+2)^2-4(D+2)+5}\sin x\hspace{20pt}\cdots\text{by applying rule 2.}\\
&=4e^{2x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{D^2+1}\sin x\\
&=4e^{2x}\cdot x\cdot\dfrac{1}{2D}\sin x\hspace{70pt}\cdots\text{by applying rule 1.}\\
&=2xe^{2x}\cdot\dfrac{1}{D}\sin x\\
&=-2xe^{2x}\cos x.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

If we take the homogenous differential equation:
$$ y''-4y' + 5y = 0 $$
Its characteristic equation:
$$ r^2 - 4r + 5 = 0$$
has roots
$$ r = 2 \pm i $$
meaning the homogenous equation has general solution
$$ y(x) = c_1 e^{2x}\cos x + c_2 e^{2x}\sin x $$
Therefore, in finding a particular solution to the differential equation:
$$ y''-4y' + 5y = 4e^{2x}\sin x $$
so an undetermined coefficients assignment of:
$$ h(x) = Ae^{2x}\cos x + B e^{2x}\sin x $$
will not work, as $h(x)$ solves the homogenous equation. So we make the following undetermined coefficients assignment (and maintain $h$ in the equations to simplify solving for $A$ and $B$):
\begin{align*}
y(x) &= x(Ae^{2x}\cos x + B e^{2x}\sin x) \\
&= x h(x) \\[7pt]
y'(x) &= h(x) + x h'(x) \\
y''(x) &= 2h'(x) + x h''(x)
\end{align*}
So:
\begin{align*}
y''(x) - 4y'(x) + 5y &= x h''(x) + 2h'(x) -4[h(x)+xh'(x)]+5xh(x) \\
&= x[h''(x)-4h'(x)+5h(x)]+2h'(x)-4h(x) \\
&= x\cdot 0 + 2h'(x) - 4h(x) \\
&= 2h'(x) - 4h(x) \\
&= 2[(2A+B)e^{2x}\cos x + (-A+2B)e^{2x}\sin x] - 4[Ae^{2x}\cos x + Be^{2x}\sin x] \\
&= 2Be^{2x}\cos x - 2Ae^{2x}\sin x
\end{align*}
In order for $y$ to be particular solution to:
$$ y''-4y' + 5y = 4e^{2x}\sin x $$
it follows that
$$ A = -2 \qquad\qquad B = 0 $$
meaning the particular solution is:
$$ y(x) = -2x e^{2x}\cos x$$